# Cannot get after effects to show up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, after-effects

I cannot get my after effects animation to show up, it has a height of 2 pixels.I've tried moving it to other parts of the page too

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/customer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/Material-Icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/Montserrat-Roboto.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">

<div class="container">
    <div class="card animation-card">
        <div id="Animation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card login-card border-0">
        <div class="card-header login-card-header bg-white border-0">
            <h4 class="client-login-text">Login</h4>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="assets/bodymovin.js"></script>
<script src="assets/index.js"></script>
```

Animation should show up when page loads, If I inspect I can see the div animation card only has a height of 2 pixels.

Comment: You have not included bootstrap.js in your code.

Comment: It's in there, I just included the relevant parts.